# How to encrypt nfs which is mounted on AWS ec2

Tags: linux, nfs, encryption, amazon-ec2

We have netapp volumes attached to EC2 instance. these are nfs , which are sync with on premise and make sure data in on premise and that of NFS which is mounted on EC2 are in sync.

even though netapp provided kms encryption to the volumes at EC2 end, we need to have our own encryption in place for this NFS at EC2 level.

we mount the NFS volume to EC2 using user-data script, which has below command:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,hard,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,vers=3,tcp <ip>:/data-sharedfs application
```

now we need to add encryption while mounting this volume.

Tried to use `ecryptfs` but didn't worked.

How to encrypt that data?

Comment: You haven't explained what "didn't worked" is! 
 Is it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/277578 ?

Comment: no. that's not the case.
If I get the proper steps to be follow, would be helpful.

Comment: For somebody to help you they need to know what went wrong. So include that.

Comment: Wondering if you googled this before asking.  A search *"How to encrypt NFS"* on Google gave me many good links including this one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/efs-encrypted-file-systems/encryption-of-data-in-transit.html does that help?

Comment: I want to encrypt the data, not the traffic. on google I am getting on wire encryption. I am interested in encryption at rest.
and it is not EFS.
It is NFS volume which is getting in sync with on premise using netapp.
though netapp provides KMS encryption, we require extra encryption at mount level